# How can I install packages without download on Debian?

Tags: debian

I installed Debian 7 on another system. I want to copy installed packages (exe file) on my system and paste on the other system.
so, it does not need to download and install.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be pretty cumbersome to install packages manually, because of the dependencies. But you could put the package that you want to install on a USB stick or similar, and then copy them to the other machine. From a console you could install it with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want a way that omit the dpkg -i file.deb step:)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a Local, Private, or Proxy repository.

You may find that page of interest. This is about Ubuntu, but it should work the same with Debian since the tools at that level are the same.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository

You could also have a full mirror, but that would mean download the entire archive which is great if you have 100+ servers, but not so useful otherwise.

https://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror

Finally, to answer your question fully, if the package is available on your CD or DVD, then you could install from that media. But I understand that you want the latest version and thus need at least one download.